# In Kotlin, HashSet contains elements that are duplicate by hash

Tags: kotlin, set

I have a variable declared as follows:

```
val done = HashSet<StudentProgrammeState>()
```

At the end of processing, it is checked as follows:

```
if (done.distinctBy { it.hashCode() }.size < done.size ) {
    println("Duplicate states were evaluated.")
}
```

This message appears every run. Since `done` is a `HashSet`, how can it ever contain multiple items which are not distinct by `HashCode`?

Here are the equality methods for `StudentProgrammeState`:

```
class StudentProgrammeState(val program: Program) {
    val instances = HashSet<StudentModuleInstance>()

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (!(other is StudentProgrammeState)) return false
        return (other.program == program) && 
          (other.instances.containsAll(instances) && 
          instances.containsAll(other.instances))
    }
    override fun hashCode() = Objects.hash(program, instances)
```

`Equals` here does not directly check the `hashCode` of `instances` but that test should correspond to unordered set equality.

And for studentModuleInstance:

```
typealias StudentModuleInstance = Pair<Module, Int>
```

Since `Pair<>` is an inbuilt `data class` it should have a Kotlin generated `equals` and `hashcode` method.

The value of `program` is set as the same for all instances under consideration.

Comment: HashSet puts different items with the same hash code into the same bucket, but if they're not equal, they still both end up in there. It's just less efficient to look them up afterwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[HashSet.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-) provides this contract:

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
>       More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set
>       contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)).
>       If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
>       unchanged and returns false.

In particular, `hashCode` is not mentioned. hashCode uniqueness is not relevant to the add method: multiple items with the same hash code *will* go into a hash set.

Items with the same hashCode but not equals will end up in the same bucket, which decreases the performance of `get()` for those items. But other than that, hashCode isn't important.

Comment: This is proper behavior for a HashSet, regardless of language. The hash is used as a performance optimization for fast lookup.

Comment: Actually it's just copy of java method's description:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)

Comment: Actually actually, it's just the java method. Check the link :)